# Why I am getting " ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/ant': Operation not permitted "

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a Dockerfile that I am using to build a job called "ccsmp" on Jenkins.

Following is my Dockerfile-

```
FROM oraclelinux:8

# Setup basic environment stuff
ENV container docker
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV TZ EST

# Base image stuff
#RUN yum install -y zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite sqlite-devel openssl-devel vim yum-utils sssd sssd-tools krb5-libs krb5-workstation.x86_64

# CCSMP dependent
RUN yum install -y glibc-devel.i686 krb5-devel
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN yum install -y make gcc java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tar perl maven svn

# Minor changes to image to get ccsmp to build
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm
RUN cp /usr/include/linux/stddef.h /usr/include/stddef.h


RUN wget https://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip
RUN unzip apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip && mv apache-ant-1.10.12/ /opt/ant && ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr

CMD /bin/bash
```

But I am getting the following error-

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/ant': Operation not permitted
```

I narrowed it down to this line-

```
RUN unzip apache-ant-1.10.12-bin.zip && mv apache-ant-1.10.12/ /opt/ant && ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant
```

Is there any way to solve this issue. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: A bit confused, is it a typo that your line with `ln` fails with a message mentioning `ls`?

Comment: Honestly its not, I am also very confused, plus I'm new to Docker so even more confusing for me.

Comment: The dockerfile builds correctly on docker 4.7.1 on my Mac, so I'm not sure I can help with your specific problem, sorry. At least it does not seem to be dockerfile related.

Comment: It builds fine for me as well but when I try to run a job on jenkins, using this docker image I get this error.

Comment: Is this in the context of a Docker Compose workflow?  It's possible to cause Compose to accidentally overwrite the `FROM` image with the image you built if you have an incorrect `image:` line, and that could then cause this problem on a rebuild.

Comment: No, so I have a jenkins job called "ccsmp", I load my docker image at the start of this job and then trying to run ant -version, just to see if ant works. But I keep getting the above mentioned error.